# Adding fields to an object with if-statement in js

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement

Im trying to aggrigate huge array of objects to single object, but my if statements replace each other:

```
const obj = [];
res.map((el) => {
    if (el.resource.name === "FORM01" && el.name === "cost.ttl") {
        obj[el.resource.name] = { [el.name]:  el };
    }
    if ( el.resource.name === "FORM01" && el.name === "cost.use") {
        obj[el.resource.name] = { [el.name]:  el };
    }
});
```

in result I want to add in

```
obj[el.resource.name] = {}
```

two fields like `cost.ttl` and `cost.use`.

Comment: A small example of the "_huge array of objects_" might help to solve the problem ..?

Comment: What end result are you looking for?

Comment: It was my mistake I declare obj as {}. And T.J. answer suits well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using the result, `map` isn't the right tool for looping through an array. Similarly, if you're mapping strings to values (`el.resource.name` to an object), an array isn't the correct object type to use. Just use a plain object, or a `Map`.

The reason your two assignments are conflicting is that the second time the condition is true, it *overwrites* the first object you've assigned. Instead, create an object, then add each property to the *same* object as necessary.

It's not clear what end result you're really looking for, but perhaps something like:

```
const obj = {};       // *** Object, not array
res.forEach((el) => { // *** forEach, not map
    if (el.resource.name === "FORM01" && (el.name === "cost.ttl" || el.name === "cost.use")) {
        // *** Get the existing object if any; create and store a new one if there isn't already one there
        const entry = obj[el.resource.name] = obj[el.resource.name] || {};
        // *** Add this property to it
        entry[el.name] = el;
    }
});
```

or you might use `for-of`:

```
const obj = {};
for (const el of res) {
    if (el.resource.name === "FORM01" && (el.name === "cost.ttl" || el.name === "cost.use")) {
        const entry = obj[el.resource.name] = obj[el.resource.name] || {};
        entry[el.name] = el;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thx very much, it really helped me. I understand that it was not correct and not very nice code. Now I know how to do it right and nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
const obj = {}; // Initialize here to an object instead of array
res.map((el) => {
    if (el.resource.name === "FORM01" && (el.name === "cost.ttl" || el.name === "cost.use")) {
        // Check for existing object, else create new object
        obj[el.resource.name] = obj[el.resource.name] || {};
        obj[el.resource.name][el.name] = el; // set the value in object
    }
});
```

**Note**, `Array.map` is not the correct choice over here for iteration as you are trying to loop over the array and get some value on an condition and store it. You can either use a simple for loop, or `forEach`.

Comment: At a guess: Code dumps are not useful answers (the OP is supposed to guess at what you did, and why?), and `map` is the wrong tool if not using the array it creates. *Edit:* Oh, and what Jeremy said. :-)

Comment: I believe you got downvoted because `obj` should be an object. `obj[el.resource.name]` won't work on an Array, and your code didn't fix this.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Agreed. Adding details

Comment: @JeremyThille - Ideally you are right, however, you can also set a property to array as well just like an object. Though I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid two `if` statements in a row, because the first one could affect the data tested by the second one.

Also, `obj` should be an Object, not an Array.

Also also, use `.forEach`, not `.map`, because you're not returning anything from the loop.

```
const obj = {};
res.forEach( el => {
    if (el.resource.name === "FORM01" && ["cost.ttl","cost.use"].includes(el.name)) {
        obj["FORM01"] = { [el.name]:  el };
    }
});
```

Comment: You seem to be overwriting `obj["FORM01"]`

Comment: So does everyone else, because this condition implies `el.resource.name === "FORM01"`. Therefore `obj[el.resource.name] === obj["FORM01"]`.

Comment: Thx, ill try this solution also. It much cleaner then my)

Comment: @JeremyThille - I meant you are resetting. It will only have one key at the end of loop

Comment: Yes, I understood what you mean, and I repeat my previous comment :) If `el.resource.name === "FORM01"` then, writing `obj[el.resource.name]` is exactly the same as writing `obj["FORM01"]`. So, I did it. This is what OP's code does.

Comment: I do get that. But when you are assigning it with =, you are basically resetting it. Hence, the resultant object will have only 1 key/value pair. And OP does not want that